# Recursive Functions not return

Tags: python

I'm playing with recursive functions and I'm not figure out why the function is not return if the list is empty ([]) even if the print function before the return is executed.

```
def go(mylist):
if not mylist:
    print('Empty list')
    return 'List Empty'
else:
    print(mylist)
    mylist.pop()
    go(mylist)

print(go([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

I get return 'None' because a function without a a return always return 'None'

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the value that you received from the recursive call:

```
return go(mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer.